# What face parts can OpenCV detect on iOS?

Tags: opencv, face-detection

For my new iPhone app I like to use OpenCV for detecting face elements with the purpose of morphing faces. Does anybody know what elements need to be detected for this, and if it's even possible with OpenCV? Are there perhaps better alternatives?

Comment: Check this out http://answers.opencv.org/question/313/facial-feature-detection/#318

Comment: I think you are asking in the wrong place...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [dlib](http://dlib.net) for detecting facial landmarks, there is 68 points:
 [image]

Here is very useful project: https://github.com/zweigraf/face-landmarking-ios

Answer (score 0):

Opencv has eye, ear,mouth, nose, eye pair detector cascades.